# Huffman tree and order of nodes in terms of occurrence

Tags: java, huffman-code

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for Huffman coding, I have a very simple code at the moment that works fine. In my code, the weight of the character is based on the frequency of occurrence of that character, however I would like to improve it so that it meets the following criteria:

I would like my code to consider the order in which a node is encountered. For example if ’e’ and ’ ’ have the same frequency, but ’e’ occurs first, its weight would be considered greater. I have been trying to implement this for my code but it seems to give me mixed results.

Here is what I have. Any input on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated. I apologize in advance if this is too simple, but I'm a student and still learning.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Huffman {

static Node node;
static Node newRoot;
static String codedString = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String message = "'twas brillig, and the slithy toves  did gyre and gimble in the wabe:  all mimsy were the borogoves,  and the mome raths outgrabe.  "
            + "\"beware the jabberwock, my son!  the jaws that bite, the claws that catch!  beware the jubjub bird, and shun  the frumious bandersnatch!\"  "
            + "he took his vorpal sword in hand:  long time the manxome foe he sought --  so rested he by the tumtum tree,  and stood awhile in thought.  "
            + "and, as in uffish thought he stood,  the jabberwock, with eyes of flame,  came whiffling through the tulgey wood,  and burbled as it came!  "
            + "one, two! one, two! and through and through  the vorpal blade went snicker-snack!  he left it dead, and with its head  he went galumphing back.  "
            + "\"and, has thou slain the jabberwock?  come to my arms, my beamish boy!  o frabjous day! callooh! callay!\" "
            + " he chortled in his joy.  'twas brillig, and the slithy toves  did gyre and gimble in the wabe; "
            + " all mimsy were the borogoves,  and the mome raths outgrabe.";

    // Convert the string to char array

    char[] msgChar = message.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();

    /*
     * Get a List of all the chars which are present in the string No
     * repeating the characters!
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < msgChar.length; i++) {
        if (!(characters.contains(msgChar[i]))) {
            characters.add(msgChar[i]);
        }
    }

    /* Print out the available characters */
    // System.out.println(characters);

    /* Count the number of occurrences of Characters */
    int[] countOfChar = new int[characters.size()];

    /* Fill The Array Of Counts with one as base value */
    for (int x = 0; x < countOfChar.length; x++) {
        countOfChar[x] = 0;
    }

    /* Do Actual Counting! */
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
        char checker = characters.get(i);
        for (int x = 0; x < msgChar.length; x++) {
            if (checker == msgChar[x]) {
                countOfChar[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Sort the arrays is descending order */
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfChar.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < countOfChar.length - 1; j++) {
            if (countOfChar[j] < countOfChar[j + 1]) {
                int temp = countOfChar[j];
                countOfChar[j] = countOfChar[j + 1];
                countOfChar[j + 1] = temp;

                char tempChar = characters.get(j);
                characters.set(j, characters.get(j + 1));
                characters.set(j + 1, tempChar);
            }
        }
    }

    /* Print Out The Frequencies of the Characters */
    for (int x = 0; x < countOfChar.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(characters.get(x) + " - " + countOfChar[x]);
    }

    /* Form the Tree! */

    /* Form Leaf Nodes and Arrange them in a linked list */

    Node root = null;
    Node current = null;
    Node end = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfChar.length; i++) {
        Node node = new Node(characters.get(i).toString(), countOfChar[i]);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            end = node;
        } else {
            current = root;
            while (current.linker != null) {
                current = current.linker;
            }
            current.linker = node;
            current.linker.linkerBack = current;
            end = node;
        }
    }

    // Recursively add and make nodes!
    TreeMaker(root, end);

    // inOrder(root);
    System.out.println();
    inOrder(node);

    // preOrder(root);
    System.out.println();
    preOrder(node);

    // Calculate the ends and the meets!
    char[] messageArray = message.toCharArray();
    char checker;

    for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
        current = node;
        checker = messageArray[i];
        String code = "";
        while (true) {
            if (current.left.value.toCharArray()[0] == checker) {
                code += "0";
                break;
            } else {
                code += "1";
                if (current.right != null) {
                    if (current.right.value.toCharArray()[0] == characters
                            .get(countOfChar.length - 1)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    current = current.right;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        codedString += code;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The coded string is " + codedString);
}

public static void preOrder(Node root) {

    if (root != null) {

        System.out.print(root.value + "->");
        preOrder(root.left);
        preOrder(root.right);

    }

}

public static void inOrder(Node root) {

    if (root != null) {
        inOrder(root.left);
        System.out.print(root.value + "->");
        inOrder(root.right);
    }

}

public static void TreeMaker(Node root, Node end) {
    node = new Node(end.linkerBack.value + end.value, end.linkerBack.count
            + end.count);
    node.left = end.linkerBack;
    node.right = end;
    end.linkerBack.linkerBack.linker = node;
    node.linkerBack = end.linkerBack.linkerBack;
    end = node;
    end.linker = null;
    Node current = root;

    while (current.linker != null) {
        System.out.print(current.value + "->");
        current = current.linker;
    }

    System.out.println(current.value);

    if (root.linker == end) {
        node = new Node(root.value + end.value, root.count + end.count);
        node.left = root;
        node.right = end;
        node.linker = null;
        node.linkerBack = null;
        System.out.println(node.value);
        newRoot = node;
    } else {
        TreeMaker(root, end);
    }
}
```

}

class Node {

```
String value;
int count;
Node left;
Node right;
Node linker;
Node linkerBack;

Node(String value, int count) {

    this.value = value;
    this.count = count;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.linker = null;
    this.linkerBack = null;

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "its weight would be considered greater"?

Comment: Weight refers to frequency of occurrence. Sorry if that was unclear! @mark

Comment: It's not crystal clear to me where you're going with this, but if all you want to do is give an advantage to symbols that come before, among symbols with the same weight, one approach would be to scale all population counts by 256, say, and then add 255 to the first symbol's count, 254 to the second, and so on, and then build the Huffman tree based on these new, skewed pop counts.